# Can you reference an instance of class inside its own initializer?

Tags: python, python-3.x, syntax

I have a class that is being initialized with another class as one of its args, and that class needs to be initialized with a reference to the class being initialized. I've found a method that works, but it's not very elegant. Wondering if there's another way to handle this case?

**Example Working Code**

```py
runner = ActionRunner(
    file_support=None
)
runner.file_support = FileSupport(
    action_runner=runner
)
```

**Example Idea (Non-working)**

```py
runner = ActionRunner(
    file_support=FileSupport(
        action_runner=runner
    )
)
```

Comment: you have cyclic dependency, which looks like a poor design to me

Comment: In what way is the working code "not very elegant"? Looks fine to me.

Comment: I would probably get ActionRunner to instantiate the FileSupport in is own init, passing self as the parameter.